# Passing multiple strings to grep from txt file

Tags: string, file, grep

Is it possible to pass multiple strings in grep command from a text file (not manually)?

For example:

I have stringsfile containing:

```
aa
cc
dd
```

And a search file containing:

```
aa text1
bb text2
cc text3
dd text4
```

I want this output:

```
aa text1
cc text3
dd text4
```

I want contents of stringfile to be passed in grep command like this:

```
cat searchfile.txt | grep (stringsfile.txt)
```

I have a string file of thousand records and it is impossible to add grep strings manually.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to to this job robustly with a single call to grep but trivial and commonplace with awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a' stringsFile searchFile
aa text1
cc text3
dd text4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -f stringsfile.txt searchfile.txt
```

Here, `grep` uses option `-f file` : Obtain patterns from *file*, one per line.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)

Comment: That would produce false positives for many possible input values.